# Collect SharedFlow (with externalCoroutineScope) at viewModelScope, how to avoid keep collecting upstream even after viewModel is destroyed?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

```
class XxxViewModel : ViewModel() {
    ...

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            someSharedFlow.collect {
                // do something
                Log.i(TAG, "I'm alive")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for the above situation, found the log msg keeps showing even the `XxxViewModel` is gone (activity destroyed), how to avoid this?

PS: the `someSharedFlow` is using another coroutine scope in `XxxRepository`

Comment: That shouldn’t be the case. How are you verifying the ViewModel was destroyed?

Comment: Activity A and Activity B both are collecting the sharedFlow, and .onEach { log } to know, after Activity B destroyed, B's log is still keep showing, which means it still keep collecting.

Comment: The reason of this behaviour, by my understanding, is because the SharedFlow is using another coroutine scope for .shareIn(...), so if simply using Flow won't hit this.

Comment: Yes, activities should never use `viewModelScope`, because if you reference anything from inside your activity in the coroutine, you are leaking the activity to the ViewModel. ViewModels should never reference anything from an activity. Your question above says the coroutine stays alive after the ViewModel is gone, but that's not what you described in your comment or the answer below. The ViewModel outlives the Activity, so the ViewModel is not destroyed. It is destroyed when there are no activities or fragments holding a reference to it.

Comment: yea you're right, I tried to improve the title and content, see if it make more sense now? thanks a lot for your comment anyway :)

Comment: If you want it to help future readers, I think the key info is not that the view model was destroyed (because it wasn't) but that you used a viewModelScope from inside an Activity.

Comment: the viewModelScope haven't being used in Activity, XxxActivity use XxxViewModel, they're separated as the code stated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to collect the flow at `Activity`/ `Fragment` instead at `ViewModel`, by this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    someSharedFlow
        .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle)
        .onEach {
            // do something
        }
}
```

edit: found another behaviour, if you just want to collect the `SharedFlow` once only, this can also end the `viewModelScope` `job`, at `ViewModel`:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    someSharedFlow
        .take(1)
        .onEach {
            // do something
        }
}
```

as I can't google someone talk about such `SharedFlow` use cases, and this is the behaviour I've tried out, hope can help someone struggled like me.

> Kotlin version 1.7.10

Comment: Flow collection should happen inside of ViewModel, not Activity.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky pls take a look https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines